# How can I disabled/lock certain settings components

Tags: root-access, settings, restricted-profiles

I'm trying to find a way to disable or lock certain settings components for Android Tablet. We need to protect the tablets from out students pressing un-allowed settings. Kindly assist

We need to hide:
- Apps
- Backups & Reset
- Accounts
- Accessibility
- Developer options

Screenshots attached to be more accurate, thank you in advanced?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try using an app locker to put a password on the settings app.

Comment: I did use that however WiFi switching was locked as well, I wanna keep WiFI free to be managed. Plus Some apps were able to be uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using an EMM that supports COPE devices and MDM but that costs per device per month and some technical experience. More info here: https://androidenterprisepartners.withgoogle.com/emm/.
If you don't want to pay for an EMM you can use an open source one like WSO2 but you need to set up your own IoT server running 24/7 and you need a good technical background to understand the instructions. Mind you that doesn't prevent students from rooting the phone and uninstalling the app, so you can only really use this method if the students are not too tech-savvy.