# How to lock settings on Android 9?

Tags: settings, lg, android-9

Is there a way to prevent settings on an Android phone from being accidentally changed? I am using an LG K30 running Android Pie. (Yes, I know it's a dinosaur)

Comment: Hi, we have some related questions regarding this: [How to lock some parts of Settings?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/164913/44325), [Is there a way to disable access to certain Settings components?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/24061/44325), [How can I disabled/lock certain settings components](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/159295/44325)